# How to use regex to match css elements

Tags: css, regex

I'm calling `indexOf` on the head section in `jQuery`. I want to see if CSS contains any `font-weight:bold` property. The issue is, that property can have 4 alters:

1. `font-weight:bold`
2. `font-weight: bold`
3. `font-weight :bold`
4. `font-weight : bold`

How can I match this using regex?

Comment: I'm concerned that the approach here may be very problematic. What are you trying to accomplish, that couldn't be accomplished by testing an element like `var isBold = $(someSelector).css('font-weight') == 'bold'`?

Comment: well, the code i provided were an example only. actually, what im trying to do is to understand if page direction is rtl or not when body css set to direction:rtl. jquery doesn't read direction property, only dir property.

Comment: `$(someSelector).css('direction')` seems to work for me...? It also works correctly with inheritance (e.g. the style is set on a parent of the element I'm inspecting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

```
\b(?:font-weight\s*:[^;\{\}]*?\bbold)\b
```

or would be better to use:

```
\b(?:font-weight[\s*\\]*:[\s*\\]*?\bbold\b)
```

**Explanation**

```
\b                # Assert position at a word boundary
(?:               # Match the regular expression below
   font-weight       # Match the characters “font-weight” literally
   [\s*\\]           # Match a single character present in the list below
                        # A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
                        # The character “*”
                        # A \ character
      *                 # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   :                 # Match the character “:” literally
   [\s*\\]           # Match a single character present in the list below
                        # A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
                        # The character “*”
                        # A \ character
      *?                # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   \b                # Assert position at a word boundary
   bold              # Match the characters “bold” literally
   \b                # Assert position at a word boundary
)
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: `[^;]*?` is too permissive (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HcpSQ/1/), why not use `\s* instead?

Comment: I still don't understand why `\s*` isn't enough here... `\bfont-weight\s*:\s*bold\b` should do.

Comment: I still don't understand the advantage of `[^;\{\}]`. It would still match something like `font-weight: invalidcssbutitstillsays-bold`. @Kobi jinx.

Comment: Because if any other styles come within text, still that pattern would not fail.

Comment: @Cylian, you mean you *want* to match `font-style: normal; something-else: bold;`?

Comment: The only thing that could really be there is CSS comments: `font-weight /* 1 */ : /* 2 */ bold /* 3 */`. That would be a shame.

Comment: @Kobi: I think you're right, my thought wrong. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `font-weight:bold;` could also be set as [an integer 700](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-weight) or through a shorthand [`font` notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font) which expands the range of strings to match quite a bit.

```
\b(?:font.*?:[^;]*?\b(bold|700))\b
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/84mHk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/font-weight\: bold|font-weight\:bold|font-weight \:bold|font-weight \: bold/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = "font-weight\s?:\s?bold"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regular expressions for that. CSS may contain strings like so

```
.foo{ content: "font-weight:bold;" }
```

You need a proper parser. Luckily the browser has one and offers [APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration#Example) to access the individual CSS rules.